# Installing libpng1.5.15 for Stepmania?

Tags: 12.04

I'm trying to install Stepmania on here, following these instructions: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138685.

For some reason, I'm having trouble installing/updating `libpng`. I downloaded the `.tar.gz` file to Downloads and extracted it there. I entered the `cd Downloads/libpng-1.5.15` command in the terminal. When I enter the next one, though (`./configure –prefix=user/local/libpng`), I get an error message that says:

```
./configure--prefix=usr/local/libpng: No such file or directory
```

I tried going to `/usr/local/` and creating a folder called `libpng`, but it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command in the thread (and the command you typed) is incorrect.

From your error message, there are two mistakes:

- There should be a space between `./configure` and `--prefix`.
- The correct path is `/usr/local/libpng`, not `usr/local/libpng`; there should be a `/` before the word `usr`.

So, the correct command you should use is:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/libpng
```

Answer (score 0):

Better make sure you are in the directory where the file you wanna run is in... I dont think it will work otherwise lol.

Comment: He said he already did `cd Downloads/libpng-1.5.15`, so he's definitely in the directory.

Comment: oh ok well fine then